# Using Charles to debug HTTP request to an endpoint with unusual port number which needs a proxy to be accessible

Tags: proxy, http-proxy, charles-proxy

I'm using Charles as a proxy to debug some HTTP requests. However, one of the endpoints is www.myendpoint.com:9064 and I need a proxy (myproxy.com:80) to access it. When I try to debug it with charles it fails to connect to that endpoint. Do I need to do any extra configuration for this case?

Comment: I don't know if I clearly understand your case... As I understand, you are trying to debug HTTP requests to www.myendpoint.com:9064 through a proxy (myproxy.com:80), so to access this endpoind you configure your browser's (or system) proxy to myproxy.com:80 and obviously you can't reach it through Charles because it changes the proxy, right?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I have the proxy configured on my code since it's needed to access that endpoint but Charles is probably replacing it.

Answer (score 1):

Charles Proxy automatically tries to configure your system's proxy ([in Windows and macOS](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/configuration/browser-and-system-configuration/)) so by this many applications, such as browsers, use it automatically.

By what you say in your comment, you seem to be developing an application, which I guess you configured to use the `myproxy.com:80` proxy.
Being this the case, what **you need to** do is to **configure your application to use the Charles Proxy**, which usually opens up at your `localhost:8888,` instead of the `myproxy:80.`

This will make your application access the internet through the Charles proxy and thus your HTTP request will start to appear to the Charles overview window, but the requests will still not be able to reach `www.myendpoint.com:9064`. 
To do so, you need to configure your proxy values (`myproxy.com:80`) on the `External Proxy Settings` (`Proxy -> External Proxy Settings...`) on Charles.

This will make Charles be able to reach your endpoint.

Comment: Which comments?